# courious about server prefix routing

Tags: routes, subdomain, web

I just noticed a very interesting thing today, when I tried going to sfu.ca I would get server timeout where as www.sfu.ca would work perfectly.

I was wondering what could be causing this, is it because they manually have added www as a subdomain? Does the browser not default to www.* when no prefix is provided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're doing it wrong. sfu.ca should redirect to www.sfu.ca or vice-versa. An no, your browser doesn't automatically add the 'www'.

NSlookup for 'sfu.ca' gives me this:

```
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   sfu.ca
Address: 142.58.103.24
Name:   sfu.ca
Address: 142.58.190.137
Name:   sfu.ca
Address: 142.58.103.18
```

While doing the same for www.sfu.ca returns this:

```
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   www.sfu.ca
Address: 142.58.102.68
```

I prefer urls without the www. It's seems rather archaic. But I think it's best to have both options available.